# You (or a program) have requested information from hupkyeihlu

Tags: windows-xp, networking, virus, malware

This message is popping-up in my other laptop that is not connected to the internet.

Not sure what it is, is this an indication that I have a virus or something?

Additional Info:

- AVG Virus scan didn't find anything.
- I am not using this laptop for a long time and it is usually connected to WIFI immediately so this message never comes.
- So when I tried using the laptop again (after some months) without internet, that message pops.

Comment: No other info? Did you at least try a virus scan? were you doing something when this happened? don't just answer my questions either think about what someone may need to help you fix this problem.

Comment: The fact it happened without wifi connection is really important +1 for a good update.

Comment: An image of the popup would help track down it's source. Can also use a tool like SysInternals Process Explorer to find out what task owns the popup's window. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) by clicking the target icon in the toolbar and draging it over the popup.

Comment: It looks like it is a standard windows popup, asking to connect to internet. See http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/ask-a-how-to-question/nureFNRko0U as an example, where the dialog pops up because of a Google tool. hupkyeihlu is the weird thing about this. Maybe it is a LAN box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 1):

Something is trying to connect to the web.
It happens when your not connected to the web, chances are good it Also happens when you Are connected to the web, the dial-up does not Ask to connect to go to the location shown.

You could hide the problem , by making various changes to the system. That would be what others have done. Instead,  it would be much better to discover **what** is attempting to connect to the web.

Use `netstat -ab`  in a CMDprompt to find out  program names that are connecting to the web.  Problem with this is , it would have to be connected or connecting at the time or recently.  (reduce all other connections to keep the list as small as possible)

Check the registry run lists, for oddly named run items, or use MSconfig and HijackThis or other startup program viewers , and manually find the program that is doing it. Test in Safe mode, with the wi-fi not connected. (because most 3rd party programs and drivers will not be running in safe)

Re-check your spelling on the name that it shows, and check for the name on the web. (just in case it is spelled wrong and that is why it doesn't come up)

It very well could be a item connecting to the web that is not known in specific AV or Spy databases, or it is connecting for legitimate purposes. You could start trying a bunch of different spybot s&d and online AV and malware scans, and other fixes, till you run out of them.
OR
  I just think you can probably locate it yourself , either through the process of elimination (disabling run items). Knowing what should and should not be running on the system, or Oddly named , random named or Fake system named items.  Test everything even that odd piece of software that you have had for ages, that might be hopping off to the web to check for updates.